# Como visualizar el campo nombre referenciado por su ID en CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: cakephp

tengo tres tablas (Locales, Rutas y Programaciones):

Tabla Locales:

```
   id   |   nombreLocal
--------------------------
    1       Local Uno
    2       Local Dos
    3       Local Tres
```

Tabla Rutas:

```
   id   |   id_local_origen   |   id_local_destino
--------------------------------------------------
    1             1                    2
    2             2                    3
```

Tabla Programaciones:

```
   id   |   id_rutas
---------------------
    1          1
    2          2
```

Tengo las siguientes asociaciones:

En la tabla Locales:

```
$this->hasMany('Rutas', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id_local_origen'
    ]);

     $this->hasMany('Rutas', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id_local_destino'
    ]);
```

En la tabla Rutas:

```
    $this->belongsTo('Origen', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id_local_origen',
        'className' => 'Locales',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Destino', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id_local_destino',
        'className' => 'Locales',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $this->hasMany('Programaciones', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id_rutas'
    ]);
```

En la tabla Programaciones:

```
    $this->belongsTo('Rutas', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id_rutas',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

Lo que necesito por ahora amigos por favor, es resolver usando el ORM de CakePHP 3.6 lo siquiente en el view.ctp

En el index.ctp de Programaciones debe salir algo asi:

```
   id   |   Origen   |   Destino
------------------------------------
    1      Local Uno     Local Dos
    2      Local Dos     Local Tres
```

============== En el controlador de Programaciones tengo esto:

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    $programacione = $this->Programaciones->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Rutas']
    ]);

    $this->set('programacione', $programacione);
}
```

**

> En otras palabras, tengo las tablas A, B, C
>   A ya esta relacionada con B y viceversa.
>   B ya esta relacionada con C y viceversa.
>   Lo que quisiera saber por favor es ¿Cómo puedo obtener campos de la tabla A, estando en la tabla C?

**

Comment: Hola KacosPro, pues pude intentar hasta aqui: $programaciones = $this->paginate($this->Programaciones->find()->contain(['Rutas']));

        $this->set(compact('programaciones'));

Comment: Te debo una disculpa, leí mal y pensé que lo querías en el `view` por eso te pedí esa función, en todo caso te dejé una respuesta basandome en el `index`. En cuanto a la pregunta a mi parecer estaba muy bien formulada ya que contenía un excelente [mcve] pero es "política" pedir lo que se ha intentado. Cualquier duda o comentario dejame saber en los comentarios de mi respuesta :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP nos permite hacer anidaciones en los contain, y como ya has hecho la mayoría del trabajo declarando las relaciones, puedes llamarlos de esta manera:

En tu ProgramacionesController

```
public function index()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => [
            'Rutas' => [
                'Origen',
                'Destino'
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $programaciones = $this->paginate($this->Programaciones);

    $this->set(compact('programaciones'));
}
```

Y en la vista como sea que la tengas, puedes utilizarlos de esta manera para obtener el resultado que deseas

En tu index.ctp

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Origen</th>
        <th>Destino</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($programaciones as $programa): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $programa->id ?></td>
            <td><?= $this->Html->link(
                $programa->ruta->origen->nombreLocal,
                [
                    'controller' => 'Locales',
                    'action' => 'view',
                    $programa->ruta->origen->id,
                ]
            ) ?></td>
            <td><?= $this->Html->link(
                $programa->ruta->destino->nombreLocal,
                [
                    'controller' => 'Locales',
                    'action' => 'view',
                    $programa->ruta->destino->id,
                ]
            ) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Lo que nos imprimirá algo similar a esto:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Origen</th>
      <th>Destino</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a href="/locales/view/1">Local uno</a></td>
      <td><a href="/locales/view/2">Local dos</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><a href="/locales/view/2">Local dos</a></td>
      <td><a href="/locales/view/3">Local tres</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias KacosPro; pero ahora me salió otra duda. ¿Cómo implemento esta misma lógica, pero para el "edit.ctp"... pero en un control de opciones y que me aparezcan los nombres de los locales?

Comment: En el modelo debes asignarle a tu `$this->setDisplayField('id');` el valor de nombreLocal de esta manera: `$this->setDisplayField('nombreLocal');`. No dudes en abrir una pregunta nueva si tienes problemas con gusto responderé.

Comment: Hola @KacosPro, por favor ¿podrías visitar este enlace para que me puedas ayudar con otra pregunta? </br> (https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/172061/90144)