# ¿Cómo lleno opciones en un control de formulario desde una tercera tabla en el "edit.ctp" en CakePHP 3.X?

Tags: cakephp

tengo tres tablas (Locales, Rutas y Programaciones):

Tabla Locales:

```
   id   |   nombreLocal
--------------------------
    1       Local Uno
    2       Local Dos
    3       Local Tres
```

Tabla Rutas:

```
   id   |   id_local_origen   |   id_local_destino
--------------------------------------------------
    1             1                    2
    2             2                    3
```

Tabla Programaciones:

```
   id   |   id_rutas
---------------------
    1          1
    2          2
```

Tengo las siguientes asociaciones:

En la tabla Locales:

```
$this->hasMany('Rutas', [
    'foreignKey' => 'id_local_origen'
]);

 $this->hasMany('Rutas', [
    'foreignKey' => 'id_local_destino'
]);
```

En la tabla Rutas:

```
$this->belongsTo('Origen', [
    'foreignKey' => 'id_local_origen',
    'className' => 'Locales',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->belongsTo('Destino', [
    'foreignKey' => 'id_local_destino',
    'className' => 'Locales',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);

$this->hasMany('Programaciones', [
    'foreignKey' => 'id_rutas'
]);
```

En la tabla Programaciones:

```
$this->belongsTo('Rutas', [
    'foreignKey' => 'id_rutas',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

*Necesito resolver*

En el edit.ctp de Programaciones debe salir algo así:

[image: Esto es el template de edit.ctp de la tabla programaciones]

En el controlador de Programaciones, tengo lo siguiente en la acción Edit:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $programacione = $this->Programaciones->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $programacione = $this->Programaciones->patchEntity($programacione, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Programaciones->save($programacione)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The programacione has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The programacione could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('programacione'));



    // Enviando rutas
    $tabla_rutas = TableRegistry::get('Rutas');
    $query = $tabla_rutas->find('list', [
                'keyField' => 'id_rutas',
                'valueField' => ['id_local_origen','id_local_destino']
            ]);
    $rutas = $query->toArray();
    $this->set(compact('rutas', $rutas));
    debug($rutas);
}
```

En el debug obtengo esto:

```
[
    (int) 1 => '1;2',
    (int) 2 => '2;3'
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este caso podemos declarar una [`virtual property`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties) en la Entity.

Para esto agregamos la función `_getRutaName()` dentro de la clase Ruta

Ruta.php

```
public function _getRutaName()
{
    $rutaName = '';

    if (
        !empty($this->_properties['origen']->nombreLocal) &&
        !empty($this->_properties['destino']->nombreLocal)
    ) {
        $rutaName = $this->_properties['origen']->nombreLocal . ' - ' .
                $this->_properties['destino']->nombreLocal;
    }

    return $rutaName;
}
```

En la Table debemos decirle que su displayField sea la nueva propiedad virtual que acabamos de declarar, siguiendo las convenciones de CakePHP será el nombre con "underscore"

En RutasTable.php

```
$this->setDisplayField('ruta_name');
```

Y por último en el controlador llamamos al arreglo que desplegaremos en nuestra vista, **es importante** que por medio de la magia del query builder de CakePHP llamemos al contain con *Origen* y *Destino* para que existan en `$this->_properties` en el Entity.

A los parámetros del `find` vamos a pasarle como argumentos el `'keyField' => 'id'` con el id de la ruta a guardar y con el `'valueField' => 'ruta_name'` con nuestro nuevo virtualField

ProgramacionesController.php

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $programacione = $this->Programaciones->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $programacione = $this->Programaciones->patchEntity($programacione, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Programaciones->save($programacione)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The programacione has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The programacione could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }

    $query = $this->Programaciones->Rutas->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'id',
        'valueField' => 'ruta_name'
    ])->contain(['Origen', 'Destino']);
    $rutas = $query->toArray();

    $this->set(compact('programacione', 'rutas'));
}
```

Por último en la vista llamamos normalmente como lo hacíamos antes con la magia del FormHelper de CakePHP, sugiero remover el parámetro `'empty' => true` ya que si es elegido agregará como `id` 0 produciendo resultados inesperados

```
<?= $this->Form->control('id_rutas', ['options' => $rutas, 'empty' => true]) ?>
```

Esto nos dará como resultado algo similar a esto:

```html
<div class="input select"><label for="id-rutas">Id Rutas</label>
  <select name="id_rutas" id="id-rutas">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Local uno - Local dos</option>
    <option value="2">Local dos - Local tres</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @KacosPro, me funcionó de maravilla... si no fuese mucha molestia, ¿Podrías darme link sobre cakePHP avanzado, a parte de la misma página del mismo?

Comment: @CARLOSB. todo lo aprendí directamente de la documentación oficial y el código fuente  si sabes inglés dan cursos en línea los del core team, en su página de twitter lo anuncian. Igual cualquier duda yo estoy suscrito a la tag de Cake así que no dudes en crear una pregunta